# IBM MQ Broker - How to send message between 2 message flows

Tags: web-services, ibm-mq, messagebroker

I created 2 message flows, the 1st flow put message in queue and the 2nd flow must read it, transform and reply to the 1st. But I have a trouble with reading in the 2nd flow. Can you give some advices? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Your message actually lacks a lot of details about your flows, but generally, 
if the initial request is performed via HTTP, you have to do the following:

1) To save reply identifier when you receive request, so that it could be restored before sending response

```
SET OutputRoot.XMLNSC.MyBody.MyReplyId = CAST(InputLocalEnvironment.Destination.SOAP.Reply.ReplyIdentifier AS CHARACTER) // for SOAPInput node
SET OutputRoot.XMLNSC.MyBody.MyReplyId = CAST(InputLocalEnvironment.Destination.HTTP.RequestIdentifier AS CHARACTER)     // for HTTPInput node
```

2) To restore reply identifier before sending response

```
SET OutputLocalEnvironment.Destination.HTTP.RequestIdentifier = CAST(OutputRoot.XMLNSC.MyBody.MyReplyId AS BLOB)   // HTTPReply node
SET OutputLocalEnvironment.Destination.SOAP.Reply.ReplyIdentifier = = CAST(OutputRoot.XMLNSC.MyBody.MyReplyId AS BLOB) // SOAPReply node
```

Comment: You should also set in compute  -  basic >> Compute Mode * = "Local Environment and Message"